# Replication conflict: a modify of 'entry name' was rejected because it had an older timestamp

Tags: amazon-ec2, timestamp, ldap, ibm-cloud, ntp

I have 4 ldap servers (2 on-prem & 2 on cloud). We have a replication where all servers replicate to each others (All are master nodes).

In the last two mounths, some users are reported issues related to password expiration issues and I can see in the logs some entries:

GLPRPL074W Replication conflict: a modify of 'entry name' was rejected because it had an older timestamp.

To solve this previusly, I configurated in cloud servers Amazon Time Sync Service to sync time between cloud servers to EST time, equals to on-prem time.

Any suggestion of what could be the solution for this.

I was tinking in implement a NTP in all 4 servers but if I'm open to options